# iphone opaque background logo?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How would I go about adding an opaque logo to the background of a simple scrollview with text on it?  I want the logo to stay still while the text scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try putting a `UIImageView` with the logo behind your `UIScrollView`, and set your `UIScrollView`'s [`backgroundColor`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor) to be transparent. I'd test that out myself, but my MBP is booted into Windows at the moment.

Comment: How do I add an image to the UIImageView?  Can I do that in builder or xcode?

Comment: You can use either. But for simplicity you shuld probably use whatever you're using to build your existing view.

Comment: I can add the UIImageView in builder but how do I add an actual image?